# cell in first row - half of the border doesn't lie in margin area

Tags: css

Why half of the left border on the first cell doesn't lie in a margin area of table?

It happens only for the cell in FIRST row:

[image]

In other rows, the half of the border sits in margin area as it should:

[image]

The dark border on the images is table container and table has margin-left set on 0px. I use collapse border model.

```css
body{
  margin-left:50px;
  border:2px solid grey;
}
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  margin-left:0px;
}
.cellborder{
  border-left:20px solid orange;
}
td{
  background-color:gainsboro;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellborder">data1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="">data2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can help out better.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *may be* because `<table>` takes the first row as a role model for organizing the widths and stuff for the next ones. I was able to fix it by giving an empty `<tr>` in the first:

```css
body {
  margin-left: 50px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.cellborder {
  border-left: 20px solid orange;
}
td {
  background-color: gainsboro;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellborder">data1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="">data2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's strange that it is not described in W3 specification in section where they mention collapse border model: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/tables.html, part: 17.6.2 The collapsing border model

Comment: @DusanCani Even I am trying to find something that supports my argument. But we have got something that works. `:)`